# How to replace MySQL enum values for sorting

Tags: mysql, sorting, enums, translation

I have a mysql table with an enum field storing the state of elements, e.g.:

- draft
- inactive
- published

These states get translated into the user's locale in the application, and since the translations can differ greatly, it is not possible to sort records by state in the Mysql query, since the order of the enum values will not match the order of the translated strings.

For example:

```
SELECT state FROM records ORDER BY state ASC
```

Would give the following results for english, german and french:

1. draft » Draft / Entwurf / Ébauche
2. inactive » Inactive / Inaktiv / Inactif
3. published » Published / Freigeschaltet / Publié

**As Mysql sorts by the enum values, using this order in the application makes it seem like the sorting by state is jumbled**.

Of course it is possible to do the sorting by state afterwards in the application using the translated strings, but it would remove a layer of complexity to be able to do this directly in the query - as well as improve application performance.

One solution I found would be to use a CASE statement in the query:

```
SELECT
    CASE state
        WHEN 'draft' THEN 'Entwurf' 
        WHEN 'inactive' THEN 'Inaktiv' 
        WHEN 'published' THEN 'Freigeschaltet'
    END
FROM
    records
ORDER BY
    state ASC
```

Are there better/faster ways to sort an enum by custom strings translated in the application?

Comment: Create a separate table with state terms for every language. Store only `stateID` and `languageID` in the main table.  Join them and `ORDER BY` the corresponding field from the new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ORDER BY FIELD(state, opt1, opt2, opt3....)`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field

as its just a CSV list you should be able to use the application to pass the order you want.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the quickest solution you can get would be to create a translation table along the lines of:

```
TABLE myEnum
    lang VARCHAR(2)
    keyValue VARCHAR(32)
    localeValue VARCHAR(32)
```

Then fill the table with your translations of the enum, and use this table in a join in your SQL Query:

`SELECT r.state FROM records r, myEnum e WHERE e.lang = 'de' and e.keyValue = r.state ORDER BY e.localeValue ASC`

You'll probably not want to use those table or column names, of course.